# Is it okay to have a method in the before block of a series of RSpec unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, hook

I have a pretty elaborate set-up to change the condition from passing to failing for four composing methods of a method called eligible?.

```
describe "#participant_age_eligible?" do
        it "returns whether participant is age-eligible" do
          @part.participant_age_eligible?(@pers).should == true
        end

        it "returns false if participant is not age eligible" do
          q = @survey_section.questions.select { |q| q.data_export_identifier ==
                                                 "#{OperationalDataExtractor::PbsEligibilityScreener::
                                                    INTERVIEW_PREFIX}.AGE_ELIG" }.first
          answer = q.answers.select { |a| a.response_class == "answer" && a.reference_identifier == "2" }.first
          Factory(:response, :survey_section_id => @survey_section.id, :question_id => q.id, :answer_id => answer.id, :response_set_id => @response_set.id)
          @part.participant_age_eligible?(@pers).should == false
        end
      end

      describe "#participant_psu_county_eligible?" do
        it "returns whether participant lives in eligible PSU" do
          @part.participant_psu_county_eligible?(@pers).should == true
        end

        it "returns false if participant coes not live in an eligible PSU" do
          q = @survey_section.questions.select { |q| q.data_export_identifier ==
                                                 "#{OperationalDataExtractor::PbsEligibilityScreener::
                                                    INTERVIEW_PREFIX}.PSU_ELIG_CONFIRM" }.first
          answer = q.answers.select { |a| a.response_class == "answer" && a.reference_identifier == "2" }.first
          Factory(:response, :survey_section_id => @survey_section.id, :question_id => q.id, :answer_id => answer.id, :response_set_id => @response_set.id)
          @part.participant_psu_county_eligible?(@pers).should == false
        end
      end
```

There are two more methods just like those two. What I'd like to do is extract the

```
 q = @survey_section.questions.select { |q| q.data_export_identifier ==
                                                     "#{OperationalDataExtractor::PbsEligibilityScreener::
                                                        INTERVIEW_PREFIX}.AGE_ELIG" }.first
              answer = q.answers.select { |a| a.response_class == "answer" && a.reference_identifier == "2" }.first
              Factory(:response, :survey_section_id => @survey_section.id, :question_id => q.id, :answer_id => answer.id, :response_set_id => @response_set.id)
```

portion into a method in the before block and then pass the relevant parameters, but I hesitiate because I have never seen someone define a method in a before block, not even sure you can do it, further, I'm not sure if you even should do it even if you can, maybe it's pointing to a problem that I'm not seeing. So I though I'd ask the unfathomably enormous expertise of the SO community. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always define methods within your specific rspec file, and then call them from anywhere in that file. For example:

```
# your_file_spec.rb
describe MyModel do
  before(:each) { setup_variables }

  describe ...
  end

  # I usually put my helper methods at the bottom
  def setup_variables
    # Do some work
  end
end
```

You can also sometimes use a 'scenario outline' approach to your work, for example:

```
# your_file_spec.rb
describe MyModel do
  examples = [{:name => "Joe", :login => "joe18"}, {:name => "Grace", :login => "grace12"}]

  examples.each do |example|
    it "logs in #{example[:name]}." do
      # Do some work
    end
  end
end
```

You may also find that useful.

Comment: Yeah I went with making a helper method at the bottom, although it seems a bit strange, almost like it's violating scoping rules to call a method upstream of it's definition, but maybe Rspec loads the whole file first? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah everything is loaded first. You could write a `before(:each)` that was in the middle of your file, and it would still work, even if it doesn't make the most sense. You can also write helper methods in other files and store them in say `spec/support` and include them in your spec helper, or on a per spec basis.